# How can I prevent from adding more and more new objects when pressing F to change formation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquadFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle, Triangle
    }

    [Header("Main Settings")]
    [Space(5)]
    public Transform squadMemeberPrefab;
    [Range(4, 100)]
    public int numberOfSquadMembers = 20;
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfSquads = 1;
    [Range(0, 4)]
    public int columns = 4;
    public int gaps = 10;
    public int circleRadius = 10;
    public float yOffset = 0;
    [Range(3, 50)]
    public float moveSpeed = 3;
    [Range(3, 50)]
    public float rotateSpeed = 1;
    public float threshold = 0.1f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int randSpeedMin = 1;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int randSpeedMax = 1;
    public bool startRandomFormation = false;
    public string currentFormation;

    private Formation formation;
    private List<Quaternion> quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();
    private List<Vector3> newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool move = false;
    private bool squareFormation = false;
    private List<GameObject> squadMembers = new List<GameObject>();
    private float[] step;
    private int[] randomSpeeds;
    private int index = 0;
    private int numofobjects = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        numofobjects = numberOfSquadMembers;
        if (startRandomFormation)
        {
            formation = (Formation)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Formation)).Length);
        }
        else
        {
            formation = Formation.Square;
        }
        currentFormation = formation.ToString();
        ChangeFormation();

        foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform)
        {
            if (child.tag == "Squad Member")
                squadMembers.Add(child.gameObject);
        }

        randomSpeeds = RandomNumbers(randSpeedMin, randSpeedMax, squadMembers.Count);
        step = new float[squadMembers.Count];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (numofobjects != numberOfSquadMembers)
        {
            numofobjects = 0;

            numofobjects = numberOfSquadMembers;
            squadMembers = new List<GameObject>();

            FormationSquare();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            randomSpeeds = RandomNumbers(randSpeedMin, randSpeedMax, squadMembers.Count);
            foreach (int speedV in randomSpeeds)
            {
                if (index == randomSpeeds.Length)
                    index = 0;

                step[index] = speedV * Time.deltaTime;
                index++;
            }

            ChangeFormation();
        }

        if (move == true)
        {
            MoveToNextFormation();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeFormation()
    {
        switch (formation)
        {
            case Formation.Square:
                FormationSquare();
                break;

            case Formation.Circle:
                FormationCircle();
                break;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 FormationSquarePositionCalculation(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * gaps;
        float posY = (index / columns) * gaps;
        return new Vector3(posX, posY);
    }

    private void FormationSquare()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        Transform go = squadMemeberPrefab;

        for (int i = 0; i < numofobjects; i++)
        {
            if (squadMembers.Count == 0)
                go = Instantiate(squadMemeberPrefab);

            Vector3 pos = FormationSquarePositionCalculation(i);

            go.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
            go.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
            go.tag = "Squad Member";
            go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            newpositions.Add(go.transform.position);
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = true;
        formation = Formation.Circle;
    }

    private Vector3 FormationCirclePositionCalculation(Vector3 center, float radius, int index, float angleIncrement)
    {
        float ang = index * angleIncrement;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }

    private void FormationCircle()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        Vector3 center = transform.position;
        float radius = (float)circleRadius / 2;
        float angleIncrement = 360 / (float)numberOfSquadMembers;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquadMembers; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = FormationCirclePositionCalculation(center, radius, i, angleIncrement);

            var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(center - pos);
            pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
            pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
            newpositions.Add(pos);
            quaternions.Add(rot);
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = false;
        formation = Formation.Square;
    }

    private void MoveToNextFormation()
    {
        if (randomSpeed == false)
        {
            if (step.Length > 0)
                step[0] = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            squadMembers[i].transform.LookAt(newpositions[i]);
            if (randomSpeed == true)
            {
                squadMembers[i].transform.position =
            Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                squadMembers[i].transform.position =
                Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[0]);
            }
            if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i]) < threshold)
            {
                if (squareFormation == true)
                {
                    Vector3 degrees = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(degrees);
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternion, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternions[i], rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] RandomNumbers(int min, int max, int howMany)
    {
        int[] myNumbers = new int[howMany];

        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            myNumbers[i] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);
        }

        return myNumbers;
    }
}
```

In the constructor I'm searching for childs with the tag Squad Member.
But the List squadMembers will be empty since the script is attached to a new empty GameObject without any childs.

Then also the variable step will be empty.
Then inside the method MoveToNextFormation I'm checking if step is empty or not:

```
if (step.Length > 0)
                step[0] = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

If not checking the it will throw exception since there is nothing at index 0 it's null. But then if step is empty there will be no speed/s at all for the objects movements.

That's one problem.
I'm not sure even why in the constructor I did the part with the children and the "Squad Member" tag. I'm not creating yet any children with this tag so I'm confused about what I tried to do in the constructor.

The second problem is in this lines in the FormationSquare method:

```
if (squadMembers.Count == 0)
                go = Instantiate(squadMemeberPrefab);
```

But if squadMembers is empty then it will throw exception somewhere else in other places in the code. And I'm creating new objects inside the FormationSquare method that's since I'm starting by default with the FormationSquare but what if I want to start by default with the FormationCircle method ?

The idea is to start with minimum (1) number of squads and with minimum (4) number of members in the squad when starting the program. Or to start with any range between min and max. But it's all messed up.

Comment: what you exactly want to do ? first of all create the algorithm then go step by step if you think you can be confused while creating script then note it on notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would separate the squad member prefab instantiation from the squad shape formatting, doing this will help you identify your bug.

For example add the following methods and use them during 'Start':

```
void AddSquadMember() 
{
   // Use this to instantiate/spawn a new game object prefab.
}

void AddSquadMember(GameObject object) 
{
   // Use this for game object already in the scene. (.eg the children with your tag)
}
```

Then on the formation methods remove the intantiate calls and just use whatever game object you have in the list.

Finally, I would toss the 'numofobjects' variable. Then use 'squadMembers.Count' instead of both 'numofobjects' and 'numberOfSquadMembers' assuming that during 'Start' you have taken care of instantiating all game objects in order to 'numberOfSquadMembers == squadMembers.Count'. That is because you might need to raise the squad with a few more members during gameplay.